# Google Analytics shows custom event in realtime reports and debug view, but event count is always 0

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

As the title says, I send a custom event, tagged as a Conversion from a button in JS:
`window.dataLayer.push({event: 'reserve_button_click'})`.
The event triggers the Tag Manager, and the Tag Manager correctly sends it to Google Analytics (the event shows up both in Preview in Tag Manager and in DebugView in Analytics). I can also see the realtime events under Reports, happening from real users: [image: Realtime View]

However, in any reporting view, the event doesn't show up at all, and Conversions always show 0:
[image: Events View]
[image: Conversions]

Created events from scratch and reconfigured both Tag Manager and Analytics, yet the event doesn't show up in reports.

Comment: The built-in report you showed has the metric `User`. So there is a threshold limit. Try to use an explore report to show only `event_name`, `event_count`, `sessions`. It should be there